# How to enable a kv secret engine in vault using HTTP APIs

Tags: endpoint, hashicorp-vault

I was trying to enable kv secret engine at secret path in my vault setup..
I can easily do it using CLI

```
vault secrets enable -path=secret kv
```

But I have to make it work using Vault's HTTP APIs.

I have gone through documentation but could not find any endpoint for the above command.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is covered under the [System Backend`/sys/mounts`](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/system/mounts#enable-secrets-engine) API reference page.

Issue a `POST` request to `/v1/sys/mounts/<mountpoint>` with a payload containing the type (`kv`) and various configuration options. For `KV`, you probably want to specify `version: 2` (or type `kv-v2`) unless you want to stick to V1.

See the above link for details on the possible parameters.

Here is the example from the docs:

payload.json:

```
{
  "type": "aws",
  "config": {
    "force_no_cache": true
  }
}
```

Request:

```
$ curl \
    --header "X-Vault-Token: ..." \
    --request POST \
    --data @payload.json \
    http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/mounts/my-mount
```

Comment: so type should go as payload and /secret as endpoint. below

````
curl \
    --header "X-Vault-Token: ..." \
    --request POST \
    --data "{'type':'kv'}" \
    http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/mounts/secret
````

Comment: Indeed. I've added the example from the docs to the answer. Instead of `curl`, you may want to use a [library](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/libraries) in your language of choice.

Comment: its giving me this error : sys/mounts/secret not found

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/mounts/secret: not found

Comment: I'm assuming your Vault instance is serving on `localhost:8200`?

Comment: correct...we deployed it on kubernetes..so running the commands inside the vault container

Comment: Check your ports, that it's indeed listening on all interfaces, that it's unsealed, etc... But this is the command. You may need to open a separate question

Comment: ok,thank u for your quick response @Marc .will try it again.

Answer (score 0):

By default vault enables secret engine for version v1 (by just specifying `kv`). Version v1 does not have support for API calls or metadata for external integration. So we need to enable engine for v2 version by specifying `kv-v2`

```
vault secrets enable -path=secret kv-v2
```